# SetSharedVariable on multi-dimensional array

Tags: parallelization

I am trying to modify a multidimensional array inside a ParallelDo, but I get the error 'Symbol array is Protected'. How can I solve it? I attach here a minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
 array = Table[Table[0, {j, 1, 5}], {i, 1, 5}];
 SetSharedVariable[array]
 ParallelDo[
 For[j = 1, j <= 5, j++,
   array[[i]][[j]] = 1;
   ];
 , {i, 1, 5}
 ]
```

Comment: `array = Table[0, {j, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 5}];
SetSharedVariable[array];ParallelDo[For[j = 1, j <= 5, j++, array[[i, j]] = 1;];, {i, 1, 5}]` that works, but avoid of using cycles in mathematica code if it is possible